# Chances to gain yards (text simulation game)

Tags: c#, game

I'm making a text simulation game in C# and I've made the calculations and all. But I know there's a better, faster and more efficient way of doing this.

Basically, the first calculation is that there's a 5% chance that there would be a 80-100 yard gain and so on.

```
public static class Program
{
    public static Random r = new Random();
    public static int gained;
    public static int yardsLeft = 100;
    public static int i = 0;
    public static int chance = r.Next(1, 101);

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.Clear();

        //Console.WriteLine(BuffaloBills.TeamName + " will be facing off against the Seattle Seahawks" + "\n");
        //Console.WriteLine("The Bills starting lineup is Quarterback " + BuffaloBills.QB + ", " + "Running Back " + BuffaloBills.RB + " and Wide Receiver " + BuffaloBills.WR + "\n");

        while (yardsLeft > 0)
        {
            int[] playResult = new int[999];
            playResult[i] = r.Next(1, 4);

            switch (playResult[i])
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine(BuffaloBills.QB + " hands it off to " + BuffaloBills.RB + " for a gain of " + Calculations.Play() + " yards. \n");
                    yardsLeft -= gained;
                    i++;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine(BuffaloBills.QB + " passes it " + BuffaloBills.WR + " for a gain of " + Calculations.Play() + " yards. \n");
                    yardsLeft -= gained;
                    i++;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine(BuffaloBills.QB + " doesn't find anyone open so he rushes for a gain of " + Calculations.Play() + " yards. \n");
                    yardsLeft -= gained;
                    i++;
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

---

```
public static int Play()
{
    if (Program.yardsLeft >= 80)
    {
        if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 5)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(80, 101);
        else if (Program.chance >= 6 && Program.chance <= 12)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(60, 80);
        else if (Program.chance >= 13 && Program.chance <= 24)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(20, 60);
        else if (Program.chance >= 25 && Program.chance <= 100)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 15);
    }
    else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 79 && Program.yardsLeft >= 60)
    {
        if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(60, 80);
        else if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(20, 60);
        else if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 20);
    }
    else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 59 && Program.yardsLeft >= 40)
    {
        if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(40, 60);
        else if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(20, 40);
        else if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 20);
    }
    else if (Program.yardsLeft <= 39 && Program.yardsLeft >= 20)
    {
        if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(30, 40);
        else if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(10, 30);
        else if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 10);
    }
    else if (Program.yardsLeft < 20)
    {
        if (Program.chance >= 1 && Program.chance <= 10)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(15, 20);
        if (Program.chance >= 11 && Program.chance <= 30)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(10, 15);
        if (Program.chance >= 31 && Program.chance <= 100)
            Program.gained = Program.r.Next(1, 10);

    }
    return Program.gained;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing chance is some form of RNG?

Comment: Yes. It's an american football text simulation game. So it generates a number of how many yards are progressed each play.

Comment: I don't know american football so your numbers might be correct, but I'd like to remind you that the second argument in `Random.Next` is exclusive (not inclusive as the first argument). And BTW, how do you know  there's a better, faster and more efficient way in doing this? ;)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå looking at the code, I'm pretty sure there's at least a more *elegant*, *flexible* and *maintenance-friendly* way to go about this.

Comment: @Mat'sMug Sure, that covers the *better* part ;)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I'm not sure what you mean by the Random.Next 2nd argument is exclusive?

Comment: @Donavon The value provided in the second argument (maxValue) will never be generated, it's exclusive. E.g. , if you want to generate a random number in the range `20-30` you need to invoke like this: `r.Next(20, 31)` or `r.Next(20, (30 + 1))`. This way it might generate the number `30` but not `31`.

Answer (score 7):

You could set up a static 2 dimensional array with pre-calculated values to pass to `r.Next()` for each `yardsLeft` and `chance` combination.

e.g.
`array[80,1]` would contain `int tuple {80, 101}`

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, John! Very sensible suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

Since your step for the `yardsLeft` is exactly `20` you can replace outer `if`s with the `switch (yardsLeft / 20)` operator.

And using the following helper methods:

- Method to find index of occurrence within stacked ranges.

  ```
  private static int FindRange<T>(T x, params T[] rangeMarks)
      where T : IComparable<T>
  {
      for (int i = 0; i < rangeMarks.Length; i++)
          if (x.CompareTo(rangeMarks[i]) < 0)
              return i;
      return rangeMarks.Length;
  }
  ```
- Method to generate *gained* value:

  ```
  private static int GetGained(int x, int[] rangeMarks, int[] gainedMarks)
  {
      int index = FindRange(x, rangeMarks);
      if (index == 0) // If x < rangeMarks[0]
      {
          return r.Next(gainedMarks[0], 101);
      }
      return index == rangeMarks.Length 
          ? r.Next(1, gainedMarks.Last())
          : r.Next(gainedMarks[index], gainedMarks[index - 1]);
  }
  ```

Your code turns into the following:

```
switch (yardsLeft / 20)
{
    case 0:
        gained = GetGained(chance, new[] { 0, 11, 31 }, new[] { 20, 15, 10 });
        break;
    case 1:
        gained = GetGained(chance, new[] { 0, 11, 31 }, new[] { 40, 30, 10 });
        break;
    case 2:
        gained = GetGained(chance, new[] { 0, 11, 31 }, new[] { 60, 40, 20 });
        break;
    case 3:
        gained = GetGained(chance, new[] { 0, 11, 31 }, new[] { 80, 60, 20 });
        break;
    default:
        gained = GetGained(chance, new[] { 6, 13, 25 }, new[] { 80, 60, 20 });
        break;
}
```

Comment: It gives me 0's for some reason on every outcome.

Comment: @Donavon Possibly was `yardsLeft >= 100`. Fixed: `case 4` replaced with `default`.

Answer (score 1):

What if you want to move away from a console application and want to create a WPF application, or an ASP.NET application, etc.? You'd need to change so much code. Don't link your code so closely to the technology, instead move it to a dedicated class.

If `public static int Play()` was part of a dedicated class that handled all of the game play, you wouldn't need to have all those ugly `Program.` calls.

The logic also feels wrong: calling `Play()` updates `gained`, which is returned because you use it in `Console.WriteLine()`. Considering you call `Calculations.Play()` in each of the three `case`s, why not call it outside of the switch, don't have it return `gained` and simply use `gained`?

Also, considering that each of the `case`s is basically the same, except for the message, why not simply use the `switch` to write the message and move `yardsLeft -= gained;` and `i++;` outside of the `switch`?

[`Console.WriteLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx) can be used in the same way as `string.Format()`, so avoid concatenation.

But again: these are minor fixes, the big fix is moving all that gameplay code to a specific class and only using `Main()` in `Program` for I/O.

---

```
public static Random r = new Random();
public static int gained;
public static int yardsLeft = 100;
public static int i = 0;
public static int chance = r.Next(1, 101);
```

I'm not fond of public fields, certainly not when they're badly named: `r`.